# Is it possible to read documents folder of app by javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to read documents folder of app by javascript. Actually, I want to get an image saved on documents folder of app. How can I get images using javascript by `UIWebView` from documents folder of app?

I tried:

```
var file = '/Documents/' + possible[Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length)] + '.png'
var file = '//Documents/' + possible[Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length)] + '.png'
var file = '/Documents/' + possible[Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length)] + '.png'
var file = 'app://Documents/' + possible[Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length)] + '.png'
```

Js code:

```
function basicLoad(location) {
            var possible = ['image'];
            var file = 'img/' + possible[Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length)] + '.png'
            return {
              file: file,
              shownFile: location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + file
            };
          }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with UIImage?

Comment: UIImage is a variable type contains image. I want to read that image which is stored in a variable from js. A web page will use that image in UIWebView. @jtbandes